# Example of Generic Delegate?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming

Generic classes can declared with generic delegates as shown below but this is unfortunatelly metadata. I can not find full example:

```
public abstract class Expression
{
public static Expression<TDelegate> Lambda<TDelegate>(Expression body, bool tailCall, IEnumerable<ParameterExpression> parameters);
}
```

in here TDelegate is a Func<>. Can you write a generic class example which uses generic delegate? I could not find an example like that.

Answer (score 0):

Generic parameters wouldn't help much when constraining delegate types. There's no practical use case for this unless you want to pass a delegate type using a generic argument instead of using regular `typeof` keyword or `Object.GetType` method:

```
public void DoStuff<TDelegate>()
// vs.
public void DoStuff(Type delegateType);
```

Delegates aren't classes and they don't support inheritance and other features available to classes and interfaces. What you can do is constraining *delegate's generic parameters*.

For example, you want a `Func<T>` to constrain that `T` is `IWhatever`:

```
public void DoStuff<T>(Func<T> func) where T : IWhatever 
{
}
```